# How to use a MySQL query result in a function, when the query is created outside of it

Tags: php, mysql, function

This must be super simple, but I can't get there.

I have a simple mysql query, that I'm able to echo on the screen... no problem here.
What I want to do, is take that query result, and use it in a function.

Let say I have this query:
(I'm omiting parts of the code to simplify, the query works fine, and as I said I can do what ever I want from it outside the function)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM someTable';
$result = $db_connection->query($sql);
```

Now I want to use $result in a function.
I tried (no success):

```
function _checkQuery(){
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["Data"];
        }
    }
}
```

and also (no success):

```
_checkQuery($result);

function _checkQuery($db){
    if ($db->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row["Data"];
        }
    }
}
```

This for sure is simple... but it's past midnight, I'm 2 hours looking for a solution and can't find any... any help is apreciated.

Thank you.

- EDIT -

I just did some testing and I came to the folowing conclusion, using this piece of code:

```
function _checkHour($db){
    if ($db->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "x";
        while($row = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "y";
        }
    }
```

Conclusions:
a) echo "x" works, I get the "x" on screen, so the $db is not empty.
b) echo "y" does not work, but the function ends it's course normaly, so I assume the problem is with the line "while($row = $db->fetch_assoc()) {".
In the next answer he says I should use "fetch_assoc()" but the piece of code he presents, but I can´t it to work, the functions brakes instantly...

Comment: Your second attempt seems hopeful. You supply the result of the query as an argument to the function. The name `$db` is poorly chosen, but that doesn't affect its functionality. In the end you do `echo $row["Data"];`, but I can't tell whether your database table contains a column with the name `Data`. Why not try `echo '<pre>' . print_r($row, true) . '</pre>';` instead. That way you will see all the data in the row.

Comment: yes I have a column named 'Data' with a 'D'.
using echo '<pre>' . print_r($row, true) . '</pre>'; does works, but again only outdise the function. Check my edit for further information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not pass the $result and you run it locally, does the query work? 
The first thing to do is copy and past the $sql into mySQL with out any php.
<br
You also need to make sure the field name is Data and not data.

It should work, but there are some possibilities. 
I have no idea why you would pass the $result object. Especially when you used `SELECT *` the result object can be very large. So pass the query in the function.  If you insist on using a function.

You coding style drives me nuts. 
Because of the Intel micro-architecture, calling a function is inefficient. It has to push the current context on to the stack and when it returns it has to pop the stack. That's unnecessary overhead.  You need a good reason to use a function.   I don't see a reason here.

**NEVER** use:
`SELECT * FROM' 
Instead use:

```
SELECT `id`,`Data` FROM `some_table` WHERE 1
```

I added `id` to show how multiple columns are used. But can use just list($data)

**NEVER** use `fetch_assoc()'
Instead use:

```
while(list($id,$data) = $db-> $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);)) {
```

Now you have nice neat variables and you did not add every column of ever row into the results object ($results). And you don't have to use inefficient associative arrays.

It's much easier to catch an error if the query fails.
If your column name is `data` and you use `Data` the query will fail and you will quickly know there is a problem with the case of the column name.  By using $row['data'] there will be no error generated.
And I like to see the fields I am using from that query. 
Do you understand that when you use `SELECT *` the result object contains every column from every row.  If the table has many columns and the result has many rows you are wasting a lot of memory.  
You want to keep variables as small as possible so you do not overflow the microprocessor cache memory.
You want to keep variable local to the procedure and within called function.  You do not want global or public variables if possible. 
I was writing code in the 1970s.  I was an electrical engineer for 10 years.  I know how the the assembly code, the microprocessor micro code, and how the processor executes the micro instruction functions and how your various routine get executed.  Which is faster $i++, $i = $i + 1, or $i += 1?
Once upon a time $i++ would have been faster because Intel had an inc (increment) instruction.  They no longer have an inc instruction.

Every little thing matters. All the little stuff often adds up to be big stuff.

Comment: I don't think how assembler code is executed by Intel chips, and the efficiency thereof, has anything to do with the question: _"How do I make this code work?"_. Also, `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <conditions>` is very useful, and often used. `$result` points to the results, and it is only this pointer that is passed into the function. I can see you did put quite a bit of effort into this answer, but it doesn't really answer the question, and is, in part, misleading. For instance, `INC` and `DEC` are still [common opcodes in the x64 assembler language](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html).

Comment: I know I should not use  `SELECT * FROM' , thats why in my question I said "Let say I have this query", and not "I have this query". I only did this to simplefy. In reality I'm only extracting 3 columns: id, Data, Hora, with a WHERE to reduce it further.
So I supose using fetch_assoc() is not a problem anymore, or am I wrong?

Comment: @VicenteChazard using `fetch_assoc()` is fine, better than `fetch_array()` because that relies on the order of the results in the array.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware  not really.  You read the array into a list of variables and the array no longner exists.  `SELECT id,name,address FROM customer` do the query and read the results in to a `list();` like this:
  `list($id,$name,$address =mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM); ` See, no array.

Comment: @Misunderstood This method is bad in several ways: 1. You still rely on the fact that the order of the variables in the `list()` corresponds with the order in the query. A source of nasty bugs. 2. You expose the result of your fetch in many variables to the local, or global, scope. Name collisions are a real danger, and it is thus another source of bugs. Better use a single associative array. 3. Your method still uses an array. Obviously `mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches one, and it then assigned to the list of variables. Conclusion: Overall this is a bad idea. It will work, but that's about it.

Comment: I haven't been programming quite as long as you, but I do recognize the urgent need we had to save on every byte and operation. Those days are truly gone. Code, PHP included, should be written to be easily readable and in a way that prevents possible bugs. Yes, it might not be ultimately efficient, sometimes, but it is almost always fast enough. In PHP I find that most of the execution time is taken up by doing queries to the database. Efforts to be efficient should be concentrated there.

Comment: Where there is a query preformed in a loop with lots of iterations is the most important.  I often do medical patient analytics where I am looking at 100,000 patients and 2,000,000 lab test results preformed on the 100,000  patients serum.  What I have learned over the past 40 years of doing this, the little things add up.  I am fanatical when it comes to page load times.  Look at the horrible load times on Word Press pages.  I run all my web app pages through GT Metrics, Google Page Speed Insights.  If I don't score 100% on all their metrics, I am not pleased.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my own problem!
Finally.
Thanks to the answers this post received I managed to get back on track.

It was all due to my lack of understandiung of what is really hapening to the $result variable.

For all purposes this code does work:

```
function _checkHour($db){
if ($db->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["Data"] . '</br>'; //"Data" is valid column of the query
    }
}
```

I was thinking that $result was an simple array that could be scanned/searched/access as any array, but it turns out it's a pointer (still not sure to where it's pointing though). As I understand it, each time we scan this variable, the pointer stays at hes last location, and must be "reseted" if we want to scan it again from the beguining, using:

```
$result->data_seek(0);
```

In my case, since I was ouputing the $result for test purposes outside the function (before running the function) the pointer was already at the end (of whatever it's pointing to) and therefor had nothing else to show... it was as if it was empty.

In my case, I simply have to use the line above to "reset" my pointer and run the function as many time as I want.

If anyone can explain me exactly what is going on I would really appreciate it.
Thank you all for you help.

Comment: The result of a query is [an object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php). The `$result` variable points to this object. Internally this object has structure. Part of this structure is a result pointer, pointing at the current row. This is not the `$result` variable, that just keeps on pointing at the whole result object. It was a lucking coincidence, that both are called "pointers", that happened to point you towards a solution. This also illustrates the importance of [creating a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).